# IE media hack causes CSS not to validate

Tags: css

Because my main element contains floated elements I have had to use `float: left;` on this element to cause it to behave properly in IE. Unfortunately, this causes issues with FireFox so I resorted to a media query to only add this property for IE:

```
@media screen\0 {   /* IE 8+ only */
    main {
        float: left;
    }
}
```

This works well but now this single 'unrecognised media query' causes the CSS not to validate. Is there a way I can cause this to apply only to IE, but still manage to correctly validate the CSS?

Comment: Thank you. I only knew that IE can't cope with floated elements when it was too late! I cannot re-write the site unfortunately. My use of them was to cause images and columns to fall underneath at lower resolution, making a responsive site. Isn't this a suitable use of floats?

Comment: Does the containing div have a defined width? Did you try adding `display:inline` and the correct standards `DOCTYPE`?

Comment: The containing div doesn't have a defined width. Is `display:inline` an alternative fix for IE than `float: left`? It appears to be, and on a brief check it doesn't cause a problem with FF. Oh, and yes, I always have a valid DOCTYPE :)

Comment: @AndyG: Yes, that's the most common fix for the float issue. The bug is known to cause problems when the parent div does't have a defined width. So that might be causing it. Glad that it helped. You might want to take a look at this [**small article**](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/9-most-common-ie-bugs-and-how-to-fix-them--net-7764) about some common problems and corresponding fixes for IE.

Comment: Thank you all. You live and learn. I won't be able to re-write the site, but it seems to be working reasonably well in different media, given the very short time I had to re-write an existing Dreamweaver monstrosity. (I am not a web developer.) It's only just been completed at catraining.london if you want to offer criticisms. (I may live to regret this offer!)

Comment: Anyway, to answer the question, put the IE-only CSS inside a "downlevel-hidden" conditional comment and then the validator won't complain.